# Dynamically change translateX a div in Angular on scroll

Tags: css, angular, typescript, frontend

I'm trying to move one element to the right dynamically at the same time I'm scrolling.

So far, I've got this code that instantiates the div called *text* and the way of applying the css:

```
@ViewChild('text') text!: ElementRef;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2){}

  @HostListener('window: scroll', ['$event'])
  onScroll() {
    let transformX: Number;
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.text.nativeElement, 'transform', `translateX(${ transformX }px)`);

  }
```

However, I need a formula that calculates the translateX depending on the position that we're at.

Not forgetting that the element must be visible on screen (no overflow), thus the importance of that formula

Comment: So as you go down element should translate to right? and should not overflow left or right? is it correct?

Comment: Exactly! @YousafRaza